# How to filter last one week data on a specific day

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hi I have a MySQL database that already has auto increment date time colomn (may information help).

How to filter last one week data as start from specific day until next 7 day.

example. Show data from Wednesday on this week until nest 7 day

```
$query="SELECT * FROM diagnosa WHERE schedule= '$a'";
```

$a is start day the data start to be shown (example Wednesday)

Comment: date/time columns are not auto-incremented, so your question makes no sense.  Sample data and desired results always help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I try to fix this question

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_colunm between 'start_date' AND DATE_ADD("start_date", INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

**UPDATE :**

As you need from the Wednesday. Please us below query

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE date_colunm
        between (
            CASE
                WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) > 4
                THEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (7-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)
                ELSE (
                    CASE
                        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) < 4
                        THEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (4-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)
                        ELSE curdate()
                        END
                    )
                END
            ) as date
        AND DATE_ADD (
            (   
                CASE
                    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) > 4
                    THEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (7-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)
                    ELSE (
                        CASE
                        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) < 4
                        THEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (4-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)
                        ELSE curdate()
                        END
                    )
                    END
            ) as date, INTERVAL 6 DAY
        )
```

**NOTE :**

There are some codes for the days like for Wednesday we have 4 (as mentioned in query),
so you can change the code according to your requirements. Like for Monday is : 2

Comment: Can we change start_date into the spesific day?
Because every week data on that week must be shown

Comment: Ohh you need from the Wednesday. Please below query

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_colunm between (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) > 4 THEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (7-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY) ELSE 
 (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) < 4 THEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (4-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)ELSE curdate() END)
 END) as date AND DATE_ADD ( (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) > 4 THEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (7-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY) ELSE 
 (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) < 4 THEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (4-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)ELSE curdate() END)
 END) as date, INTERVAL 6 DAY)

Comment: There are some codes for the days like for Wednesday we have 4 (as mentioned in query), so you can change the code according to your requirements. Like for Monday is : 2

Comment: Instead of commenting here update your answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: @MukhpalSingh , sorry, I've tried to apply it, but no result

Comment: this query gives you two dates according to you(LIke for one week), may be there is some date format matching problem ,make sure you are using date or timestamp type for columns which we are using for conditions.
Or just let me know the table structure with some demo data.